# How to insert data with condition "if not exists"

Tags: sql, insert

I want to only insert rows from the B where Role||Email does not match Role||Email which already exist in A, and ignore the rest (like the NAME).

My tables are:

- Table A with three columns (NAME, ROLE, EMAIL)
- Table B with three columns (NAME, ROLE, EMAIL)

I tried the following:

```
insert into A (NAME, ROLE, EMAIL) 
SELECT NAME, ROLE, EMAIL from B 
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT ROLE, EMAIL FROM B WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.EMAIL = B.EMAIL);
```

It does not work though, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Please clean up your question by adding an orderly sample query of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding Tim and all the friends who help to improve the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into A (NAME, ROLE, EMAIL)
select B.NAEM,B.ROLE,B.EMAIL from B left outer join A 
on B.ROLE=A.ROLE and B.EMAIL=A.EMAIL
where A.ROLE is null
```

make sure you have no nulls in you ROLE column,if so, change the `A.ROLE is null` to any column in (NAME, ROLE, EMAIL) that will never be null.

Comment: outer join with null condition means those records in B have no same ROLE an EMAIL combination with A.@TimBiegeleisen.

Comment: Thanks Amow, sorry that I can not vote up for your answer because I do not enough reputation credit. Your answer is awesome, I never imagine this solution in my mind. And standing on your shoulder, I improved the answer with the consideration of nullable EMAIL, as in your query, when email is null, duplicate data from B will be inserted into B. Anyways, I appreciate for that! 

insert into A (NAME, ROLE, EMAIL)
select B.NAME, B.ROLE, B.EMAIL from B left join A
on B.ROLE=A.ROLE and nvl(B.EMAIL, 'XXX')=nvl(A.EMAIL, 'XXX') where A.ROLE is null